# StateTtlConfig if Flink job goes down

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have aggregations running for a minute window for which I have configured the StateTtlConfig to 2 minutes similar to this:

```
StateTtlConfig ttlConfig = StateTtlConfig
    .newBuilder(Time.minutes(2))
    .setUpdateType(StateTtlConfig.UpdateType.OnCreateAndWrite)
    .setStateVisibility(StateTtlConfig.StateVisibility.NeverReturnExpired)
    .useProcessingTime()
    .build();
```

Also, I am using RocksDB as state backend.

If the job goes down for more than 2 minutes, will the previous state entries remain?

Answer (score 0):

From Flink docs: https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/datastream/fault-tolerance/state/

> The state backends store the timestamp of the last modification along with the user value (...)

> Only TTLs in reference to processing time are currently supported.

So no, I'd say they will not remain. Once the task gets up again and its processing time advances, the state will expire and be eventually removed as described in here: https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/datastream/fault-tolerance/state/#cleanup-of-expired-state